# Grails Domain Object ArrayList suddenly empty

Tags: grails

I'm currently developing a grails 1.3.7 application, which will be used for organizing lectures, seminars and university related stuff. In this context, tutors should be able to assign topics the students previously selected. For that purpose, I use a simple table 'matrix' with students on the right and the available topics as table headers. Now the tutors want me to implement, that the table rows are draggable. I achieved this with a jQuery plugin, and it all works fine, but I must also save the new order of the rows somewhere, so I decided to save it as an ArrayList in a domain class. I implemented a simple logic to wipe the list and rebuild it everytime the tutor saves the topic assignments.

The code for those steps:
**Domain Class**

```
class Seminar extends  AbstractLecture {
    ...
    ArrayList<Integer> studentOrder = new ArrayList<Integer>()
    ...
```

**gsp:** The hiddenField holds the serialized representation of the new row order, set by a javascript function (works fine).

```
<g:form action="saveDistribution">
    <g:hiddenField name="order" id="order" value=""/>
    ...
```

**Controller**
The plugin serializtion function returns a string I'm breaking down here, this is also no problem and the ids are correctly contained in the list after this block.

```
def saveDistribution = {
....
    if (!params.order.toString().equals("")) {
        seminar.studentOrder.clear() //seminar is the domain object

        def temp = params.order.toString().replace('[','').replace(']','').replace("table-1=", "").replaceFirst('&', '')
        def split = temp.split("&")

        for (id in split) {
            seminar.studentOrder.push(Integer.parseInt(id)) //Works fine
        }
    }

    //If I check seminar.studentOrder here, the parsed values are present

    //Now I redirect to another function (forward would also work, doesn't matter here)
    redirect(action: "distributeTopics", id: params.id)
```

But now the big problem: When I check seminar.studentOrder right after the redirect, the list is completly empty... and I really, really don't know why. I driving me nearly insane for the last hours :(
I tried everything I could even imagine to solve this problem, but nothing is willing to work.
Now I'm urged to think that I'm missing a big point somewhere.

I appreciate everything you can contribute to solve this problem.
If you need more code, or even the complete code for this context, I will provide it.

Many thanks in advance,
Dominic

UPDATE (Complete code added for both controller functions):
Here is the code from distributeTopics:
The TopicTableDataWrapper Class is a simple Java class to gather necessary data so that I have an easier time in the gsp.
As you can see, I'm simply pulling the student objects from the database with the supplied IDs from the ArrayList studentOrder, but since the list is always empty and save doesn't work either... well, I'm stuck here.

```
def distributeTopics = {
    def seminar = Seminar.findById(params.id)
    if (!seminar) {
        flash.message = "Error: Seminar not found. (Database error?)"
        redirect(controller: "lecture", action: "list")
    }

    /*
     * Gather all students and build an ArrayList<TopicTableDataWrapper>, which will be passed to the gsp.
     */
    def wrapperList = new ArrayList<TopicTableDataWrapper>()

    if (seminar.studentOrder.isEmpty()) {
        for (student in seminar.students) {
            //Selected topics
            def topics = seminar.getPrioritizedTopics(student)
            if (topics[0] == null) {
                topics = null
            }

            //Already assigned topic
            def assigned = seminar.getAssignedTopic(student)

            //Comment
            def comment = null
            if (seminar.comments.containsKey(student.id.toString())) {
                comment = seminar.comments.get(student.id.toString())
            }

            wrapperList.push(new TopicTableDataWrapper(student, assigned, comment, topics))
        }
    }
    else {
        for (studentId in seminar.studentOrder) {
            def student = User.findById(studentId)
            if (student == null) continue

            //Selected topics
            def topics = seminar.getPrioritizedTopics(student)
            if (topics[0] == null) {
                topics = null
            }

            //Possibly assigned topic
            def assigned = seminar.getAssignedTopic(student)

            //Comment
            def comment = null
            if (seminar.comments.containsKey(student.id.toString())) {
                comment = seminar.comments.get(student.id.toString())
            }

            wrapperList.push(new TopicTableDataWrapper(student, assigned, comment, topics))
        }
    }

    /*
     * Now we also need a list of all topics.
     * It is important that the list is sorted, because we must map the topic titles to the shortcuts in the gsp!
     * We do this by building a hashmap which just maps 'T1', 'T2', ... as keys to the topics
     */
    def topicList = seminar.topics.sort()
    def map = new HashMap<String, Topic>()

    def i = 1
    for (topic in topicList) {
        map.put("T" + i.toString(), topic)
        i++
    }

    [seminar: seminar, wrapperList: wrapperList, topicMap: map, id: seminar.id]
}

def saveDistribution = {
    def seminar = Seminar.findById(params.id)
    if (!seminar) {
        flash.message = "There was a problem while retrieving the seminar (database error?)."
        redirect(controller: "lecture", action: "list")
    }

    /*
     * Parse the corresponding radiogroup for every student in the seminar
     */
    for (student in seminar.students) {
        //Look if a topic has been assigned by checking the params -> "group <student.id>"
        if (params.containsKey("group " + student.id)) {

            //if that's the case, assign him this topic, but keep his selection for later corrections!
            def topic = Topic.findById(Integer.parseInt(params.get("group " + student.id).toString()))

            //Remove previously assigned topic for this seminar
            def prevTopic = seminar.getAssignedTopic(student)
            if (prevTopic != null) {
                student.removeFromAssignedTopics(prevTopic)
            }
            student.addToAssignedTopics(topic)
        }
    }

    if (!params.order.toString().equals("")) {
        seminar.studentOrder.clear()

        def temp = params.order.toString().replace('[','').replace(']','').replace("table-1=", "").replaceFirst('&', '')
        def splitParam = temp.split("&")

        for (id in splitParam) {
            seminar.studentOrder.push(Integer.parseInt(id))
        }
    }

    flash.message = "Distribution saved."
    seminar.save(failOnError: true) //Still empty list after redirect
    redirect(action: "distributeTopics", id: params.id)
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're calling `.save()` before redirect? (it's not exist in this example). What if call it as `.save(failOnError: true)`?

Comment: This doesn't work either, the Integer objects in the list are still gone after the redirect. I also tried several .save possiblities yesterday before I posted the question, but really, nothings works.

Comment: Can you show your controller code, with `.save()` method used?

Comment: There you go, complete code added.

Comment: Did you tried to save it before, somewhere else, in Bootstrap maybe? Can you try with `List studentOrder = []` instead?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? Sorry if I'm a little bit slow, but I cannot grasp why this should be related to the problem :/

Comment: I mean that `ArrayList` can be too much specific for grails automagic, but it's just a idea

Comment: Ah ok, I'll try that. But I successfully used even more complex datastructures like HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> before in this application. I'll post the result as soon as I get back to a computer in about ~2h.

Comment: OK, i tried a more generic datatype as you suggested: List studentOrder = []. Same problem :/

Answer (score 0):

Although we are missing some parts of the code you have been writing, the comment above is probably right.

I am pasting the link to the save method for Grails object:
http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html

If the save call does not work, please add how you are retrieving objects in the  **distributeTopics** method.

Comment: Sadly, the save call does not work. I added more code in the snippets above, so that you can further look into it

Comment: Also I am not sure about the ArrayList mapping. Have you tried to:
- see what's in the database?
- do a different mapping (http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.2.4 Sets, Lists and Maps) and use the hasMany directive.

Comment: I'll try this shortly and post feedback here.

Comment: I'm pretty busy right now, but on a related note my tutor (supervising this project) mailed me the following which seems to be a bug in grails I encounter right here: [link](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-1819) and [link](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-domain-class-with-ArrayList-property-tt4301147.html#none), which seems to be the same problem. However, I'll try your suggestion in a few hours.

Comment: Ok, I now use a pretty ugly workaround with a HashMap... Domain Class: HashMap<Integer, Integer> studentOrder = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(). The first integer is simply the position number and the second one the student object id. Although that works, I'm still curious why such an all-day used simple ArrayList fails to serialize / save correctly... However, thank you (and @splix) very much for your efforts.